# UIImagePickerController Unable to select images issue?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

This is my code to present the UIImagePickerController:

```
        UIImagePickerController *imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagepicker.delegate = self;
        imagepicker.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourcheType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagepicker.sourceType = sourcheType;
        imagepicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]
This is the image where the error occurred
[image]
This is a normal picture
This happens on one iPad (iOS 11.1.2), but it works fine on the other (iOS 8.4.1). I tried the changes, but none seemed to work.

Comment: What is the issue? U are talking about choose/use button being missing out? that appears when u select the image n not when u are in album level

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot reply you in time for some reasons.
Yes, as you said, I can't find choose/use button .Could you tell me more about it.Thank you